# MySQLi Prepared Statement: Data not inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql, file, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm working on a file upload application. Every file is uploaded into the website's `/files/` directory, so not directly into the database. I've been trying it with images. 
The thing is, I also want to use a database to show every picture uploaded, together with some more information... and also to check if a file with the same name already exists.

**What the user needs to do:** Select a file he wants to upload, using a `file` input type.

**What the application does:** Firstly, it checks in the database if the file name was already used. If not, it proceeds to uploading the picture using `$_FILES` and moving it into the `/files/` folder, using the `move_uploaded_file()` function. Then, it creates a line in the database table, that contains the file's category (`fcategory` -> "Picture"), the file name (`fname`), its font-awesome icon (`ficon`), a description (`fdesc`) and a link (`flink`) that is based on `/files/$_FILES['name']`.

This is my form:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <input type="submit" class="btn" name="btn">
</form>
```

and this is the PHP code:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['btn']))
   {
      $file = $_FILES['file'];
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM files WHERE fname = ?");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $file['name']);
      $stmt->execute();
      $res = $stmt->get_result();
      $num = $res->num_rows;
      if ($num == 0) {
         move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], "files/".$file['name']);
         echo "<br><br>Image was uploaded.";
         $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO files (fcategory, fname, ficon, fdesc, flink) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
         $name = $file['name'];
         $link = "https://LINKTOWEBSITE.COM/files/".$name;
         $stmt2->bind_param("sssss", "Imagine", $name, "fa-image", "No description.", $link);
         $stmt2->execute();
         $stmt2->close();
         $stmt->close();
      }
      else
      {
         echo "<br><br>Choose another name for the image.";
         $stmt->close();
      }
   }
?>
```

I decided not to provide the link to my website. That's why I replaced it with `LINKTOWEBSITE.COM`

The problem is, data isn't inserted into the database, but the file is inserted into the `/files` folder.
Could it be because I'm using two prepared statements, nested one into another? The first statement, the one that checks for an already existing file, works perfectly. What can I do?

If you need more information, just leave a comment and I'll edit the question as soon as possible. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use only variables in bind_param. Either move these strings into the query or assign ithem to a variable first, or do like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55486423/use-php-mysqli-prepared-statements-without-references

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!! Please, write this as an answer, so I can mark my problem as solved.

Comment: There is already an answer to this question so, not need to mark another

Comment: @YourCommonSense oh, yeah, didn't see that. I wasn't sure if the problem was in my prep. statement, and that's why I didn't look for any other answers on this website. Thanks, again!